# Largest isomorphic subgraphs of two graphs with features

Tags: graphs, graph-isomorphism, features, subgraphs

the following question came up in a problem I am working on:

Suppose you have two graphs $G_1=(V_1, E_1), G_2=(V_2,E_2)$ that have features attached to them, i.e. to every $v\in V_1$ or $v\in V_2$ there is a vector $w_v\in\mathbb R^n$ with fixed $n$ of features mapped to, and similarly for all edges. We call two of these graphs isomorphic, if there exists a bijective function $f: V_1\to V_2$, such that
$$uv\in E_1\Leftrightarrow f(u)f(v)\in E_2,$$
$$w_u=w_{f(u)}\text{ and}$$
$$w_{uv}=w_{f(u)f(v)}$$
for all $u,v\in V_1$.

Given such two graphs, what would be the best way to get the *maximal isomorphic subgraphs*, i.e. a subgraph of $G_1$ induced by a set of vertices $U_1$, such that there exists an injective $f:U_1\to V_2$ like above (with $E_1, E_2$ replaced by the appropriate induced edge sets) that has a maximal amount of vertices.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds very like a $\mathsf{NP}$-hard problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it is at least as hard as the [induced subgraph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph_isomorphism_problem).  Suppose that all $w$ vectors are 0.  Then your question is identical to asking whether for a maximal induced subgraph of $G_1$ that is isomorphic to an induced subgraph of $G_1$.  The solution to your problem will be all of $G_1$ iff $G_1$ is isomorphic to an induced subgraph of $G_2$.

Consequently, your problem is NP-hard, since it is at least as hard as a problem known to be NP-hard.

Your problem can be viewed as working with colored graphs.  Typically, on practical instances, the colorings only make the problem easier, but from worst-complexity, the problem remains NP-hard.

If this is something you need to solve in a practical setting, one plausible approach is to formulate this as an instance of SAT and solve with an off-the-shelf SAT solver.  It appears that the [Glasgow Subgraph Solver](https://github.com/ciaranm/glasgow-subgraph-solver) supports induced subgraph isomorphism; I don't know whether it supports the colored version.  You could also look at algorithms for subgraph isomorphism, such as [these](https://github.com/bookug/siep), to see if they can be extended to support induced subgraph isomorphism.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I will look into this, I need to apply it in a practical setting, so I will look deeper into formulating it as a SAT instance!